# Why there is some extra `<p></p>` tags showing in the Elements inspector of Chrome?

Tags: html

Why there is some extra `<p></p>` tags showing in the Elements inspector of Chrome?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Source code is like this;

```
<div class="hint">
  <p><center class="hint-title">Tips</center></p>
</div>
```

Thanks for any kind of tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's adding extra tags because you are using an invalid tag `<center>`

```
<center></center> is not in HTML5.
```

To center text in the html code, use text-align: center; like this

```
 <p class="hint-title" style="text-align: center;">Tips</p>
```

To center text with classes in your css stylesheet do this

```
.hint-title { text-align: center; }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

Comment: Thanks! My fault. But why it's adding extra tags? Just curious why by adding two `<p></p>` before and after would fix this for Chrome

Comment: That's because it doesn't recoginze the <center> tags, so you can't put <p> tags around it. So it interprets the <p> opening tag as NOT having a close tag, and automatically adds it. Then for the ending </p> it interprets as not having an opening tag, so adds that too.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo Yep, just replace <center with <div class="centerClass and </center> with </div>  And then in css just add .centerClass { text-align: center; }  Like always though, before making any numerous changes, always backup your current code, just in case.

Comment: "That's because it doesn't recoginze the <center> tags" - Actually it's the opposite. The browser must recognise the `<center>` tag for this to happen. If you change the tag name to something random, say `<codehorse>`, the extra `<p>` tags will not be created.